# Torque cumulative creates grid

Tags: carto

How can I get Torque's cumulative setting to draw the data points in their correct locations versus artificial grids?

http://cdb.io/OAgzRD

My dataset of global locations looks fine under non-cumulative setting, but cumulative wants to add the locations in a grid that looks very artificial.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

> -torque-resolution:4

to

> -torque-resolution:1